# php wordpress cookie пустые

Tags: php, wordpress, cookie

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста разобратся почему здесь куки пустые. 


`$lang = (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) ? $_COOKIE['lang'] : 'nl';
get_header($lang);`
 
Ниже код который устанавливает куки

`ob_start();
setcookie("lang", 'fr', time() + 31536000, '/');
ob_end_flush();` 

Даная часть кода находится вверху файла category.php. Куки устанавлюются до загрузки страницы на предыдущей странице. После загрузки страницы видно через инспектор хрома что куки есть [скрин из хрома](https://monosnap.com/file/phsnaItAEmJrzgSGilU5Ioi3hqw32D). Перезагрузка страницы не помогает (тоесть это не из-за того что кук еще нету или не установлены). Возможно жизненный цыкл страницы еще не тот (я с php только начал знакомиться). Если поставить в этот момент принт всего что в куки то там только один куки 'has_js' 

`var_dump($_COOKIE); // результат => array(1) { ["has_js"]=> string(1) "1" }`

 которого нету когда страница уже загружена через инспектор хрома [скрин из хрома](https://monosnap.com/file/phsnaItAEmJrzgSGilU5Ioi3hqw32D). Спасибо.

Comment: Этот код правильный. Здесь куки пустые, потому что они пустые. Покажите код, в котором куки устанавливаются, и информацию о куках из хрома.

Comment: @KAGGDesign изменил описание в соответсвии с кодом.

Answer (score 1):

В силу ограничения протокола http, cookie [должны передаваться до того как будут выведены какие-либо другие данные скрипта](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php). Поэтому в файле category.php они работать не будут.

Правильный способ отправки куки из WordPress:

```
add_action( 'init', 'set_lang' );
function set_lang() {
    setcookie("lang", 'fr', time() + 31536000, '/');
}
```